# Dynamically set focus to another program in C#

Tags: c#

There is a running process of Visual studio 2013. I would like to set focus on that from my desktop application. My code -

```
Process[] arrProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(strProcessName);
if (arrProcesses.Length > 0)
{
    IntPtr ipHwnd = arrProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    SetForegroundWindow(ipHwnd);
}
```

I tried `Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (32 bit)`, `Microsoft Visual Studio 2013`, `Microsoft Visual Studio` as strProcessName. But none of them works.

Any help?

Comment: Ok. So u r saying that length of arrProcesses array comes as zero?

Comment: The process name may be wrong - try printing out the processes to see if there's any similar name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and try [`AppActivate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x57y7863)

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate("Visual");
```

**Update**

`AppActivate` finds only main windows whose title starts with the title parameter (the title parameter needs at least 3 characters), but the Visual Studio main window title is usually something like `Solution Name - Microsoft Visual Studio`, so you can either use the solution name or :

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv");
if(processes.Any()) 
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate(processes[0].MainWindowTitle);
```

Comment: Process {0} not found.

Answer (score 1):

```
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    private void FindAppSetFocusAndSendKeyStrokes()
    {
        TryFindWindowAndSetFocus("ThunderRT6FormDC", "Human Resource Management System");
        SendKeyStrokes("%ML{ENTER}");
    }

    private void TryFindWindowAndSetFocus(string strClassName, string strCaption)//If you can't find strClassName, use String.Empty instead.
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        int intCounter = 0;
        IntPtr processHandler = FindWindow(strClassName, strCaption);

        while (processHandler == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            if (intCounter > 9)
                break;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            processHandler = FindWindow(strClassName, strCaption);
            intCounter++;
        }
        if (processHandler == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Exception("Could not find the Process Window");

        intCounter = 0;
        while (!SetForegroundWindow(processHandler))
        {
            if (intCounter > 9)
                break;

            Thread.Sleep(500);
            intCounter++;
        }
        if (intCounter > 9)
            throw new Exception("Could not set Process foreground window");
    }
    private void SendKeyStrokes(string strKeys)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        SendKeys.SendWait(strKeys);
        SendKeys.Flush();
    }
```